# I have a problem with understanding the register %bl

Tags: disassembly, debugging, gdb

```
   0x080484ad <+0>:     xor    %ebx,%ebx
   0x080484af <+2>:     mov    (%eax),%bl   *****
   0x080484b1 <+4>:     xor    $0x52,%bl
   0x080484b4 <+7>:     cmp    $0x11,%bl
   0x080484b7 <+10>:    jne    0x8048510 
   0x080484b9 <+12>:    mov    0x7(%eax),%bl
   0x080484bc <+15>:    sub    $0x16,%bl
   0x080484bf <+18>:    cmp    $0xd,%bl
   0x080484c2 <+21>:    jne    0x8048510 
   0x080484c4 <+23>:    mov    0x1(%eax),%bl
```

I am having a problem understanding the register %bl. The register %eax has the value of "12345678" (string) under the address. I understand that in the second line we are moving the value of $eax to %bl (8 bits). So it is supposed to take the first two numbers from the string "12", right? I wish some clarify this line. Thanks a lot.

Comment: No, 8 bits is just one character i.e. `'1'`.

Answer (score 1):

at&t syntax throws me off so i would go with intel syntax
I would also stick with hex as base in my answer

if **eax** holds an address like **0x80481234** and it points to a variable like **0x12345678**
moving the byte to bl would make bl **0x78**
**0x78** is xorred by **0x52** and the result should be **0x11**
so xorring **0x52 by 0x11**  should get you the required input

[image]

Comment: @mylifeisdark If you find the answer helpful you should consider Accepting it, if you didn't already.